# creating dictionary where value is key using comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to generate a dictionary where value is a list using following dictionary of comprehension method.

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> y = {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> z = {i:[].append(j) for (i,j) in y.items() if i in x and j < 2}

>>> z
{'a': None}
```

I'm trying to get:

```
{'a':[1]}
```

Can someone please let me know how to do that? I think I'm getting None as value as it is acting as function and returning None.

Comment: You were close: `z = {k: [v] for k, v in y.items() if k in x and v < 2}`

Comment: :) awesome.This community is superb! Thanks

Comment: `[].append(j)` is `None` since all it does is append something to an anonymous list as a side effect but returns no value. `append` doesn't return a new list (or the modified list), it simply modifies one that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
x = ['a','b','c']
y = {'a':1,'b':2}

z = {key: [y[key]] for key in list(y.keys()) if key in x and y[key] < 2}
print(z)
```

output:

```
{'a': [1]}
```

**Explaination**

1. i get every key from `y` with `list(y.keys())`
2. if they key is in `x` i continue else i skip to next key
3. if above condition is satisfied i control if the `key` value in `y` is smalller than 2
4. if also the above condition is satisfied i create a new item in z with `key` as key and a list containing `y` value as value

the error rin your code was just that `[].append(j)` returned `None` so you only ad to do:

```
z = {i:[j] for (i,j) in y.items() if i in x and j < 2}
```

another weird thing is to create a list for `j` that is a single value, but, becaouse you required it in your expected output and you have surely your reasons to do that, i keeped the output as you wanted, but in general if it is a single value is better to store it directly in the dictand not create a nested list for it in a dict